# Why does "which -a" show multiple (same) entries in Git Bash for Windows?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, git-bash, git-for-windows

Output of `which -a` commands:

```
$ which -a grep
/usr/bin/grep
/bin/grep
/usr/bin/grep
/c/_Apps/bin/grep
/usr/bin/grep

$ which -a which
/usr/bin/which
/bin/which
/usr/bin/which
/usr/bin/which
```

The `/usr/bin/xxx` appears thrice.

Equivalent Windows `where` command shows unique entries:

```
$ where grep
D:\_Apps\Git\usr\bin\grep.exe
C:\_Apps\bin\grep.exe

$ where which
D:\_Apps\Git\usr\bin\which.exe
```

Git version

```
$ git --version
git version 2.33.0.windows.2
```

Entries in `PATH` environment variable (related to Git):

- D:_Apps\Git\mingw64\bin
- D:_Apps\Git\usr\bin
- D:_Apps\Git\

Notes:

- The reason the first command for `grep` shows an additional entry (`/c/_Apps/bin/grep`) is that I have a separate `grep` executable stored (along with `sed` and `wget`).
- I'm using the portable version of Git for Windows
- I tried searching Google with `"git bash" "which" command shows multiple entries /usr/bin`, but couldn't find any results (only scanned the first few entries).

Related note: I'm guessing this is why many basic Git commands are slow in my system. Even `git log` or `git status` takes a few seconds each time they run. I tried suggestions for that from other SO posts, including updating Git. None of them has worked so far.

Comment: Is `/usr/bin` in $PATH multiple times on the first system?

Comment: bash's built-in `type` command (`help type` for more information) is likely to be faster than `which` and to give you better information.

Comment: @jordanm Yes, it does. I didn't check the output of $PATH (in git bash) earlier. Removing the three entries I specified in the question removes one duplicate entry. But I'm still seeing two entries for each command. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: This is probably not why Git commands are slow, since the shell stops searching when it finds the first item.  The slowness is likely due to a non-default antivirus, firewall, or security software.

Comment: Note that "git bash" is kind of a misnomer: bash is a "shell" (a command line interpreter). Bash was originally written for Unix/Linux systems. Git needs a POSIX-compatible shell, and bash suffices for that. So to make Git run on Windows, someone ported bash to Windows. That program (bash-for-Windows) is now bundled with Git-for-Windows. People call it "git bash", but it's really just bash-for-Windows. You don't need to have Git to use it.

Comment: Unix shells work really well on Unix/Linux systems, and rather less well on Windows (for numerous reasons), but they shouldn't be painfully slow on modern hardware. As bk2204 suggests, there's probably something else going on that is slowing it down.